# Can't connect to localhost but can on another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-chrome, localhost

I've created two asp.net project recently and both were working fine before the weekend, since then I haven't touched them. I ran one and it connected to LocalHost perfecting fine, the other one when ran refused to connect to localhost saying "Site Can't Be Reach". I am using google chrome.

Comment: I tried to access "applicationhost.config" as Dryadwoods suggested but it told me I had an invalid license even though I have the free version of VS. I retried it and it worked, so not really sure what fixed it. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: if there is an answer that helped you solving the problem, then please chose it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way (using IIS express or ASP.NET Development Server) you need to have a file that matches the project to a port.

have a look and try to see if both sites are in the list (file path bellow) and verify if they match the port and settings from the project settings in visual studio (project settings > Web > Servers

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

Then confirm if the urls that you see in your browser are the same.

Other point, verify in your solution which project is pointed as "starting project".

Answer (score 0):

Is the IIS Express host running for the second project? If not you need to launch it by running the project from within Visual Studio. After that, IIS Express will keep running and the site should be reachable as long as the Visual Studio instance is open, whether or not the project is running in VS.

Answer (score 0):

as I said in my comment "I tried to access "applicationhost.config" as Dryadwoods suggested but it told me I had an invalid license even though I have the free version of VS. I retried it and it worked, so not really sure what fixed it." I am unaware of what was causing the issue and how it was rectified however Dryadwoods suggestion could have had an effect.